# Can we get dropbox short lived access token without user's interaction?

Tags: node.js, authentication, dropbox

I am working on integrating dropbox APIs for accessing files/folders from dropbox, from the dropbox dev console I am getting a access token but that was expired in 4 hours, and then APIs showing me errors.

When I further enquired then I found out that for long use I have to get refresh token from dropbox but that required user's interaction for authorization I don't want this, so I want to ask can we get the short lived token without user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

No, whether you need only a short-lived access token or both a short-lived access token and a refresh token, you need the user to manually connect the app to their account at least once.

That manual user interaction is how the user consents to having the app access their account. Apps may not access end-user accounts without that consent. This only needs to be done once per account though.